# Python instaloader get max number of followers

Tags: python, instagram

Is there a way to limit the number of followers collected by pythons instaloader.get_followers()? I'm trying to download a few of the followers of a 100k+ profile but it times out as there are to many users to download and it tries to download all of them.

```
    username = "user"
    pw = "pw"

    instaL = instaloader.Instaloader()
    instaL.login(username, pw)

    def get_names(website, follow):
        profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(instaL.context, website)
        followers = []
        if follow == "followers":
            followers = set(profile.get_followers())
        if follow == "followee":
            followers = set(profile.get_followees())
        names = []
        for follower in followers:
            names.append(follower.username)
        return names
```

So if I set website as e.g. "world_record_egg" it will just timeout even if I just want the first 100 names

Comment: Do you have any code for us to look over?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [itertools.islice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function, which allows to only get the first N elements returned by an iterator. So, to get only the first 100 followers instead of all of them, simply do

```py
from itertools import islice

followers = set(islice(profile.get_followers(), 100))
```